# Cause: trying to add non-existing file to classpath: E:\AndroidProjects\GoodCreditNum\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

AndroidStudio 3.1.4

When I try "Generate Signed APK...."

Lint gives an error.

I confirmed that there is an AndroidManifest.xml file in this path.

> Cause: trying to add non-existing file to classpath: E:\AndroidProjects\GoodCreditNum\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

**update**:

I found the code that caused the error, but I still don't understand why I am getting an error.

```
java.srcDirs += 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

When I commented this line in the gradle configuration, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to directly add `AndroidManifest.xml` to your source dirs; The Android SDK picks it up directly during build. `java.srcDirs` should contain a Java or Kotlin source dir, such as `src/main/java` (except that one is on the source search path by default).

The error message produced by lint is in error--I think if you build with `--debug` and dig deeper, you'll find another, more accurate error message saying something like "cannot unzip AndroidManifest.xml", because it's trying to treat the XML file as a source archive.